# Error Occurs in implementing the Navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have one Login Activity if user click on login button than automatically its go to Navigation Drawer but i got an error. Please Help me out from this error.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    public String emailRegistration;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_business);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        //toolbar.setTitle("toolbar");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        //Set adapter to AutoCompleteTextView

      //  FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

//        if (!emailRegistration.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+")) {
//
//            email.setError("Invalid Email Address");
//
//        }

//        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Snackbar.make(v, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
//                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
//            }
//        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        setTitle("Home");
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            setTitle("Edit Profile");
            EditFragment editFragment = new EditFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,editFragment).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            setTitle("Business");
            BusinessFragment businessFragment = new BusinessFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,businessFragment).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
            setTitle("Message");
            MessageFragment messageFragment = new MessageFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,messageFragment).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Log.d("AutocompleteContacts", "onItemSelected() position " + position);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Show Alert
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Position:"+i+" Country:"+adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("AutocompleteContacts", "Position:"+i+" Country:"+adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));

    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText email, password;
    public TextView textView;
    public Button login;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
//        if( email.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
//            email.setError("Email is required!" );
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text_input_password_toggle);
//        if( password.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
//            password.setError("Password is required!" );
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,signupactivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }



    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)' on a null object reference
```

SignupActivity. java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class signupactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText firstname, lastname, email;
    private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    public Button signup;
    String[] languages={"Indore","Ujjain","Bhopal","Delhi","Bangalore","Chennai"};
    List<CharSequence> list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        for (int i=0;i<20;i++){
            list.add("test " + i);  // Add the item in the list
        }
        firstname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        lastname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        signup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signup);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new
                ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,languages);
        actv.setAdapter(adapter);
        actv.setThreshold(1);

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(signupactivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Image [I want the blank fragment when i click on the home, edit profile but its show everywhere signup activity because my content_main framelayout id is fragment and its call in mainactivity and its my signup page too  (fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment,editFragment).commit();) So how to solve this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umgVa.png)

Comment: Hey,
In your MainActivity.java you are using  setContentView(R.layout.fragment_business);

But your drawer is in activity_main.xml
So your drawer is a null and you cannot add a listener to a null object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainActivity.java you are using

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_business);
```

But your drawer is in activity_main.xml

So your drawer is a null and you cannot add a listener to a null object.

Change the setContentView to

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Yeah, Its work now thanks but in the background its show my signup page. and i have one signupactivity too. How i remove the signup page from there? because first user signup than click on the login and than its enter in the blank navigation drawer page

Comment: It's better to post your code for better understanding. I think it's a small issue what you are facing and googling it would get the solution for you. In case you are using the fragments. Set background colour to your fragment layout and that would do the job. Or else you may just replace the fragment.